# Flutter: textAlign:TextAlign.end dosen't work in TextField/TextFormField

Tags: flutter

I have simple TextField inside a row with a Text and a TextField but it gives issue mentioned below if `textAlign:TextAlign.end` is used in TextField/TextFormField. Though `textAlign:TextAlign.start` and `textAlign:TextAlign.center` works fine.

When user types some thing for example "Hello World" and brings the cursor to the middle for example letter "o" of word "Hello" manually by tapping and presses the backspace key of android keyboard, the "Hello" word gets deleted but now cursor moves to end of the word i.e. at letter "d" of "World" but now if user press backspace it won't get deleted. Seems like the caret moves outside the input box.

Link to full [code and a video](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1CPrNrcuOWmqaNe8HVxfBMiwQRJVVVZOD)

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home:Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Demo")),
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: Text("data"),
                  flex: 2,
                ),
                Expanded(
                  flex: 2,
                  child: TextField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: "Enter Text Here",
                      border: InputBorder.none
                    ),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.end,
                    controller: TextEditingController(text: "Text"),
                  )
                )
              ]
            ),
          ]
        ),        
      )
    );
}
```

Comment: What is the error - Do you mean syntax error? I used your code and it isn't showing any error. Do let me know where get stuck?

Comment: @CopsOnRoad The error was might be because of some other issue. Have updated the question, please look into it. If you need a video please let me know.

Comment: I tried what you said, and it is working fine in my case. Where are you testing it - in phone or emulator?

Comment: @CopsOnRoad Have added a video and the full code, I have checked in both. recorded video in Android phone

Comment: Thanks for the video. If you are using `TextAlign.end` that means you are using `Directionality` of `rtl`. So, it works as it should. This is used for Arabic language and its keyboard cursor also works this way. So, the thing that you want to achieve can be achieved using Arabic language keyboard

Comment: @CopsOnRoad ok I understood but the cursor moves to end and looses focus when the text is deleted, it should stay there why does it shifts to the end.

Comment: It shifts because it knows nothing is left on the extreme left side and now it's my job to move to the starting location which is extreme right in this case. So it goes at the end.

Comment: @CopsOnRoad Then why doesn't it clears the right most words after completing its job of clearing. And user has to click to get the cursor for clearing that text. Its strange behavior. Are you able to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Yes. It's strange because we are doing something in rtl configuration using ltl stuff we have.

Comment: Its a known issue and not a common behavior.
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/21679

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My specific issue is resolved by Flutter, as of now only on DEV channel and is being tracked by [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/21679).